# Wicket listview skipping `list` tag

Tags: listview, wicket

how can i generete next list

```
<span wicket:id="listview">
   this label is: <span wicket:id="label">a</span><br/>
   this label is: <span wicket:id="label">b</span><br/>
   this label is: <span wicket:id="label">c</span><br/>
</span>
```

instead of

```
<span wicket:id="listview">
   this label is: <span wicket:id="label">a</span><br/>
</span>
<span wicket:id="listview">
   this label is: <span wicket:id="label">b</span><br/>
</span>
<span wicket:id="listview">
   this label is: <span wicket:id="label">c</span><br/>
</span>
```

If someting unclear pease write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? The wicket:container tag will not show up in the final markup.

```
<span>
    <wicket:container wicket:id="listview">
        this label is: <span wicket:id="label">a</span><br/>
    </wicket:container>
</span>
```

Comment: This way gives next result : <span>
    <wicket:container wicket:id="listview">
        this label is: <span wicket:id="label">a</span><br/>
    </wicket:container><wicket:container wicket:id="listview">
        this label is: <span wicket:id="label">b</span><br/>
    </wicket:container><wicket:container wicket:id="listview">
        this label is: <span wicket:id="label">c</span><br/>
    </wicket:container>
 </span>

Comment: Java : new ListView("listview", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" })) {
   
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   protected void populateItem(ListItem arg0) {      
     arg0.add(new Label("label",  arg0.getModel()));         
   }
  };

Comment: Looks good. Now try it in deployment mode. then it will remove the wicket:container tags.

Answer (score 0):

<span>
  <span wicket:id="repeatingView"></span>
</span>

I.e. see RepeatingView.